# No csv files found errror in magmi

Tags: magento, magmi

we are using magmi_full_0.7.19a

we placed a csv file under var/import directory.

but still we are getting mesage as : `No csv files found` in magmi page

```
Relative paths are relative to magento base directory , absolute paths will be used as is
```

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put Your csv files under the `magmi/var/import`

but generally magmi take path in `root/var/import` so make sure that you have to create a `imoprt` folder in `var`

Comment: yesterday same problem happened , you said this : http://prnt.sc/avbsjd

yester it worked , now its not working in another site.

Comment: when i use `magmi/var/import` its working, but when i gave `var/import` its not working . but actually files are in `var/import` directory only.

Comment: generally magmi take path in root/var/import so make sure that you have to create a `imoprt` folder in `var`.

Comment: you are right, i was going in wrong path. thnaks, let me chek with images now.

Comment: single images are working fine . can you give format to upload multiple images, now i am using : `/SF5093.jpg;/1.jpg` but not working

Comment: you should add extra column `media_gallery` and add images name like  `/extraimg1.jpg;/extraimg2.jpg`

Comment: nice, its  working. there are lot of columns are there  in excel sheet.

is all those columns are mandatary , is there any way to delete some columns and upload successfully ?

Comment: products are not uploading for existing categories, instead its creating in new categories. can you please help.